# Merge a simple array of values into an array of objects by adding a key

Tags: javascript

Good morning,
I'm struggling with a small problem, and I don't find an answer for my case :

I have an array of value : let's say

```
let tab = [1,2,3]
```

Then I have an array of objects :

```
let values = [
  {key1 : "a", key2 : "b", key3: "c"}, 
  {key1 : "d", key2 : "e", key3: "f"},
  {key1 : "g", key2 : "h", key3: "i"}
]
```

I would like to map the value of the array in the objects to have :

```
[{key1 : "a", key2 : "b", key3: "c", index: 1}, 
{key1 : "d", key2 : "e", key3: "f", index: 2},
{key1 : "g", key2 : "h", key3: "i", index: 3}]
```

Is there an easy to do that ?

Comment: Yes, you can use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)  loop or a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: [Objects are not JSON](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but I was thinking there is an easy way to do it, with a map or something like that but didn't figure out how

Comment: Sure you can use `.map` too and create new objects in its callback. There are many ways to do what you ask. Just take your pick. What you call *easy* is a matter of opinion.

Comment: in place (keeping the index zero based):  `myArray.forEach((item,i) => item.index = i)`

Comment: If you must use the tab: `myArray.forEach((item,i) => item.index = tab[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant "array of objects" and not "array of json", you can indeed do it with map this way:

```js
const tab = [1,2,3]

const myArray = [
{key1: 'a', key2: 'b', key3:'c'}, 
{key1:'d', key2 : 'e', key3:'f'},
{key1 : 'g', key2 : 'h', key3:'i'}];

console.log(myArray.map((element, i) => { return {...element, index:tab[i]}; }));
```

Keep in mind that map returns a new array.

If you are looking to update the original array, forEach would be a better solution :

```
myArray.forEach((item,i) => item.index = tab[i])
```

Comment: Yes sorry for the mistake.
Thank you very much I'm gonna try that in my case !

Comment: `tab[index]}`,  why not just `index + 1` ?

Comment: @keith ... because `tab[index]` most probably never is going to be equal to `index + 1` except for the OP's provided example code. But one always wants to assign the current `index` related item of the `tab` array.

Comment: Ah right, yes.  The OP did stipulate that, must have missed it.

Comment: I should probably have picked another name for the index paramater of the callback function, that's a bit confusing I agree, but yes, @PeterSeliger said it all. (PS: I don't think that deserves a downvote xD )